# What's the reason of "IPv6 feasure disabled error" while building INET 4.1.2 in WSL Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, omnet++, inet

When building INET 4.1.2 in omnet++ 5.5.1 in WSL Ubuntu, building error occurs as shown below,  with #error "IPv6 feature disabled" . However, building the same package in window environment makes no error.
What could  be the reason of the building error in Ubuntu?

```
 *** LINKING with:
g++ -shared -fPIC -o ../out/gcc-release/src/libINET.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--whole-archive  -Wl,--no-whole-archive -loppenvir -loppsim -ldl -lstdc++  -losg -losgText -losgDB -losgGA -losgViewer -losgUtil -lOpenThreads  -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil  -Wl,-rpath,/home/castrov/omnet++/omnetpp-5.5.1/lib -Wl,-rpath,/lib -Wl,-rpath,.  -Wl,--export-dynamic -L/home/castrov/omnet++/omnetpp-5.5.1/lib
Building...
inet/networklayer/configurator/ipv6/Ipv6FlatNetworkConfigurator.cc
In file included from inet/networklayer/configurator/ipv6/Ipv6FlatNetworkConfigurator.cc:24:
./inet/networklayer/ipv6/Ipv6InterfaceData.h:27:2: error: #error "IPv6 feature disabled"
   27 | #error "IPv6 feature disabled"
      |  ^~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1606: ../out/gcc-release/src/inet/networklayer/configurator/ipv6/Ipv6FlatNetworkConfigurator.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Ubuntu without using WSL. Then the INET build error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on RHEL 8.3, INET 4.2.2

It turned out that the following file was empty.

```
src/inet/features.h
```

Simply remove this file and start build again will solve the problem.